# как использовать одновременно formControlName и [(value)] в mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mat-input">
      <mat-label>User role</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(value)]="selected" formControlName="roll">
        <mat-option value="user">user</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="admin">admin</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="editor">editor</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Дефолтное значение не работает вместе с formControlName, но если я удаляю formControlName - работает.

Comment: Это рускоязычная версия! Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: убрать `value` и воспользоваться функционалом форм для манипуляций. Либо наоборот. Ловите `event` - `onModelChange()`. И в нем уже меняйте значение форы. Только тогда придется прописать [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Answer (score 0):

вместо [(value)] нужно было [(ngModel)]

Comment: formControlName и ngModel не совместимы, либо то, либо другое